# Convert Binary to text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, binary

I want to make a binary to text converter. I have already made a text to binary converter. Here is the code for that:

```
function convertText() {
    var output = document.getElementById("binaryConvert");
    var input = document.getElementById("textConvert").value;
    output.value = "";
    for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {var e=input[i].charCodeAt(0);var s = "";
    do{
        var a =e%2;
        e=(e-a)/2;
        s=a+s;
        }while(e!=0);
        while(s.length<8){s="0"+s;}
        output.value+=s;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to convert binary to text. Anyone know? Also if it is not binary they are inputting then in the textConvert box it has a value of "That is not binary you are inputting" or something like that. Here is all of my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Binary Converter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function convertText() {
    var output = document.getElementById("binaryConvert");
    var input = document.getElementById("textConvert").value;
    output.value = "";
    for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {var e=input[i].charCodeAt(0);var s = "";
    do{
        var a =e%2;
        e=(e-a)/2;
        s=a+s;
        }while(e!=0);
        while(s.length<8){s="0"+s;}
        output.value+=s;
    }
}
</script>
<noscript>
   Please enable JavaScript in your browsers settings to use this tool.
</noscript>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div class="container">
    <span class="main">Binary Converter</span><br>
    <textarea class="textConvert" id="textConvert" onKeyUp="convertText()" placeholder="Input text to convert to Binary"></textarea>
    <textarea class="binaryConvert" id="binaryConvert" placeholder="Binary text" readonly></textarea>
    <div class="about">Made by <strong>Omar Latreche</strong></div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I figured it out. Here is the code:

```
function convertBinary() {
    var bintext, textresult="", binlength;
    bintext = document.getElementById("text_result").value.replace(/[^01]/g, "");
    binlength = bintext.length-(bintext.length%8);
    for (z=0; z < binlength; z=z+8) {
        textresult += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bintext.substr(z,8),2));
    }
    document.getElementById("text_convert").value = textresult;
}
```

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: It'd be great to set the solution as an answer to mark it as accepted, so others will now that the question is solved :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use parseInt as suggested above - and consider using (+input).toString(2) to convert your  input to binary :)

```
function convertText() {
   var output = document.getElementById("binaryConvert");
   var input = document.getElementById("textConvert").value;
   output.value = (+input).toString(2);
}

function convertBinary() {
   var output = document.getElementById("textConvert");
   var input = document.getElementById("binaryConvert").value;
   output.value = parseInt(input,2);
}
```

Comment: Could you please make a JSFiddle of this? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It does for me. Had a typo in the convertBinary, but parseInt("111",2) yields 7 and (+7).totring(2) yields "111"...

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle of it please? I don't know where everything goes. I'm confused.

Comment: You have made it work in one direction (decimal->binary). I trust you to be able to make the binary->decimal work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with a radix of 2.

Ex: `parseInt('10001', 2);` returns **`17`**

And if your input string isn't valid binary, it returns **`NaN`** which you can test using [**`isNaN()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Could you show me where all of this would go please? Like put it into my code? I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

```
function binarytoString(str) {
  return str.split(/\s/).map(function (val){
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(val, 2));
  }).join("");
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.